# Using hard drive in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a virtual-box virtual machine with Ubuntu OS. I have configured a vmdk virtual hard drive. I need to use a HD I added to my PC on my virtual machine. How can I mount this HD to my virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

From Host OS, you can create a network share on the HDD you want to use on the Virtual Machine and mount that share in the Virtual Machine OS. This can be done with any directory, i.e. its not limited to entire partitions.

You will, obviously, require a network connection between Host and Virtual machines, which may require a network adapter configuration, if its not already done.

Comment: I have set up the Vbox to be in bridge mode, I have ping between the VM and host, but I cannot connect to the internet on the VM. Do I need additional configuration for the network?  In addition the HD has 3 different partition I have to set each to share and then mount it in the VM? Thanks.

Comment: Create a parent mount directory and share it to the VM. Keep your 3 partitions mounted in the parent directory. Then you can access all the partitions from single share.

Comment: Forgot about the network issue, Can you ping your gateway? If not 'mac filtering' might be enabled on your router, which is stopping you access the internet.

Comment: In most circumstances you should not need Internet access for mounting a network drive. All required modules generally come pre-installed because this is such a common thing these days.
All you need is a working network connection between Host and Virtual machines

Answer (score 0):

With the HDD attached to the host you can do the following steps to mount your drive to Ubuntu:

From a terminal run `df -H` to list available drives. From here you can find your drive with `/dev/sda1` likely being your primary virtual HDD.

Once you have your drive create a mount folder for this using `sudo mkdir /media/mountname`, obviously you can mount this wherever you want.

Finally mount your drive to this point using `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/mountname`. Replace /dev/sda2 with whatever your drive is called and you should be able to access your new drive from the mount folder.

Comment: Hi Matthew, when I run df -H in my virtual machine terminal the output is just /dev/sda1, and I do not get any other HD's in the list. Does the HD has to be Linux file system (ext3/4)?

Comment: @Kfir | It doesn't have to be a Linux file system. I personally run a HDD which has no file system on it. Use it for storage.